# Problems with CMAKE vars

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I'm using CMAKE to generate VS2008 SLN/VCPROJ files but a few simple things don't appear to work:

1)This works:     `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ($ENV{MCS_OGRE_HOME}/OgreMain/include)`

But this doesn't, my VC++ additional include dirs gets totally screwed up when I do this, brackets and all kinds floating around:

```
SET (OGRE_PATH $ENV{OGRE_HOME}/OgreMain)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${OGRE_PATH}/include)
```

2)This works: `target_link_libraries( debug $ENV{OGRE_HOME}/lib/OgreMainStatic_d.lib )`

But this doesn't, the library path isn't shown under the library paths in VC++:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES($ENV{OGRE_HOME}/lib/)
target_link_libraries( debug OgreMainStatic_d.lib )
```

I figure it must be something simple?

Comment: Does you OGRE_HOME environment variable contain '\' characters?

Comment: @tibur yes it's a standard Windows-style path. Does CMAKE not allow that?

Comment: I had some issues, with that. Could you try to replace '\' into '/' in your environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than:

```
set(OGRE_PATH $ENV{OGRE_HOME}/OgreMain)
```

Use:

```
string(REPLACE "\\" "/" OGRE_PATH "$ENV{OGRE_HOME}/OgreMain")
```

CMake uses all "/" for path separators on all platforms.

Also, it's recommended to use full path names (with "/" separators) as library arguments to target_link_libraries rather than specifying link_directories. CMake then takes the whole set of libraries linked to and figures out the right order to pass linker flags on all platforms.

One more comment: looks like you have a library or an executable named "debug" from your call to target_link_libraries. Is that true? Or are you missing the first argument in the question posted here?

Should be something like:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib
  debug /path/to/DebugLib.lib
  optimized /path/to/ReleaseLib.lib)
```

Comment: Why and where is use of `link_directories` recommended against if CMAKE has it as a feature? It makes trying to view the resulting vcproj in VS really painful

Comment: and yes there was a typo in my example about the `debug` thing, fixed now.